# Opening port 80 in router has no results

Tags: router, port-forwarding, http

A friend of mine has a ADSL modem and I need to forward some ports.

I have already forwarded the 1521 port (Oracle) and it's working fine. Now I need to forward the port 80. I already set up his IIS bindings to this port, and also forwarded the port like this video shows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLKD-fyexoo

So I think I did everything correctly. The local IP address is also the same as the machine where the IIS server is running.

I'm sorry, but I can't post images since i don't have 10 points :(

Somehow I can't forward this port, yougetsignal.com keeps saying that the door is closed.

When I try to open the port, the Control Panel says me that I have to access the control panel in the 8080 port, because the 80 port will be open. Ok, that's fine. But I'm still able to access it in the 80 port, and when I try to access it in the 8080 port, it doesn't work.

I'm trying it with the TPLINK 8816, but I also tried to open it in the Opticom DsLink 279, and it didn't worked (using another machine), I got the exact same results.

He has a dynamic IP address, but he is also using No-ip, so I can always access his Oracle database in a certain static address. The 1521 port is open.

I also tried to disable the firewall in Windows, but that makes no sense to me, since the router doesn't really open the port 80.

Clearly I'm missing something. I have never done it in my life, so I dont know how to proceed. Restarting the router was the first I did, no results. I'm accessing his laptop through TeamViewer, so I'm testing the port outside his local network.

Edit: My ISP says that they allow to open ports, and the 1521 port is opened.

What could I do to open the 80 port?

Comment: Sometimes when someone sets up a webserver for local web development purposes, they set it up so it only binds to the loopback address (127.0.0.1) so that it only accepts connections from web browsers running on the same machine. Did you test the IIS server from another machine on the LAN, by going to its private LAN IP address, to make sure the web server is accepting connections from other machines at all?

Comment: Sometimes the router itself is configured to, or has the option to, listen on port 80 over WAN for administration. Have you gone through all of the settings in the router to ensure that is not happening?

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't. I'll ask my friend to check it and I'll also let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, we did everything we could and we didn't find a solution. So we asked for help and a guy said that the router would never open the port 80, perhaps there IS a limitation imposed by the ISP. We did a workaround and now we can access through the port 8080.

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities:

1. You need to setup port forwarding, for port 80, on the ADSL modem
2. If the ISP in question does not allow forwarding of that port.
   Some ISP only allow there business customers and/or customers with static IP to have servers on them.  Verify with your ISP that they are allowing you to do that.

Comment: I tried to do it by following this tutorial: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/TP-Link/TD-8816/Utorrent.htm but got no results.


Also, my ISP is not blocking me from opening the ports (that's what they say), and the 1521 port is opened... I'll keep trying, anyway.